# How/Where to specify Room JID in QuickBlox

Tags: quickblox

I am trying to create a group chat using the JavaScript SDK, I have registered and configured the authkey etc

Where do I specify the Room JID so that the user will be connected to a particular public room?

Answer (score 1):

Create a group and join the users:

```
    QB.chat.dialog.create({type: 1, occupants_ids: '56,558,12334', name: 'Chat with Bob, Sam, Garry'}, onDialogCreated);
```

> Type = 1, indicate that the dialog is a public group.

Join users after create the group

```
    var dialog_id = '53aac0cd535c12b50600962c';
    QB.chat.dialog.update(dialog_id, {name: 'Chat with Garry and John', pull_all: {occupants_ids: [22]}}, onDialogUpdated);
```

If you want to make it in the user session. To join the group

```
    QB.chat.muc.join(jid, function() {
      // callback function
    });


    QB.chat.muc.leave(jid, function() {
      // callback function
    });
```